# Re-enable browsers' default scroll function for an element which has custom scroll function

Tags: javascript, iframe

[A news widget](http://feed.mikle.com/) applies a custom scrollbar and custom scroll function to the content wrapper. But I don't want its custom things.

I am able to overwrite its CSS and hide the custom scrollbar, but its custom scroll function still exists. (mouse wheel changes `#content_contentwrapper`'s CSS `top` property, and that mimics scrolling up and down).

How do I get rid of that custom javascript function?

Note: the widget is inside of a `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (jQuery):

If you enabled "HTML tag (img, a tag and scrollbar enabled)" in the advanced options:

```
$('#content_scrollwrapper').remove(); $('#content_mcontentwrapper').css('overflow-y','scroll');
```

If you didn't enable "HTML tag (img, a tag and scrollbar enabled)" in the advanced options:

```
$('.feed_item').show(); $('#content').css('overflow-y','scroll');
```